# Trouble predicting with tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I've trained a Deep Neural Network on the MNIST dataset. Here is the code for training.

```
n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784],name='Xx')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10],name='Yy')

input = 784
n_nodes_1 = 300
n_nodes_2 = 300


def neural_network_model(data):
    variables = {'w1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input,n_nodes_1])),
               'w2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_1,n_nodes_2])),
               'w3':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_2,n_classes])),
                 'b1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_1])),
                 'b2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_2])),
                 'b3':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}
    output1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,variables['w1']),variables['b1'])
    output2 = tf.nn.relu(output1)
    output3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(output2, variables['w2']), variables['b2'])
    output4 = tf.nn.relu(output3)
    output5 = tf.add(tf.matmul(output4, variables['w3']), variables['b3'],name='last')
    return output5

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    name_of_final_layer = 'fin'
    final = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=prediction,
                                                       labels=y,name=name_of_final_layer)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(final)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
    hm_epochs = 3
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _,c=sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict={x:epoch_x,y:epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
            print("Epoch",epoch+1,"Completed Total Loss:",epoch_loss)
            correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,'float'))
            print('Accuracy on val_set:',accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels}))
        path = saver.save(sess,"net/network")
        print("Saved to",path)
```

Here is my code for evaluating a single datapoint

```
def eval_neural_network():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('net/network.meta')
        new_saver.restore(sess, "net/network")
        sing = np.reshape(mnist.test.images[0],(-1,784))
        output = sess.run([y],feed_dict={x:sing})
    print(output)
eval_neural_network()
```

The error that popped up is :

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Yy' with dtype float and shape [?,10]
     [[Node: Yy = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,10], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

I've researched this online for multiple days now and still could not get it to work. Any advice?

Comment: You're trying to evaluate `y`, which is a placeholder that is left unassigned when you aren't training. It looks like you probably mean to pass the `prediction` tensor to `sess.run` instead of `y`.

Answer (score 0):

This complete example based on tensorflow github worked for me:
(I modified few lines of code by removing name scope for x, keep_prob and changing to tf.placeholder_with_default. There's probably a better way to do this somewhere. 
    ​

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import argparse
import sys
import tempfile
​
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
​
import tensorflow as tf
​
FLAGS = None
​
​
def deepnn(x):
  """deepnn builds the graph for a deep net for classifying digits.
​
  Args:
    x: an input tensor with the dimensions (N_examples, 784), where 784 is the
    number of pixels in a standard MNIST image.
​
  Returns:
    A tuple (y, keep_prob). y is a tensor of shape (N_examples, 10), with values
    equal to the logits of classifying the digit into one of 10 classes (the
    digits 0-9). keep_prob is a scalar placeholder for the probability of
    dropout.
  """
  # Reshape to use within a convolutional neural net.
  # Last dimension is for "features" - there is only one here, since images are
  # grayscale -- it would be 3 for an RGB image, 4 for RGBA, etc.
  with tf.name_scope('reshape'):
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
​
  # First convolutional layer - maps one grayscale image to 32 feature maps.
  with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
​
  # Pooling layer - downsamples by 2X.
  with tf.name_scope('pool1'):
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
​
  # Second convolutional layer -- maps 32 feature maps to 64.
  with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
    W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
​
  # Second pooling layer.
  with tf.name_scope('pool2'):
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
​
  # Fully connected layer 1 -- after 2 round of downsampling, our 28x28 image
  # is down to 7x7x64 feature maps -- maps this to 1024 features.
  with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
​
    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
​
  # Dropout - controls the complexity of the model, prevents co-adaptation of
  # features.
​
  keep_prob = tf.placeholder_with_default(1.0,())
  h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
​
  # Map the 1024 features to 10 classes, one for each digit
  with tf.name_scope('fc2'):
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
​
    y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
  return y_conv, keep_prob
​
​
def conv2d(x, W):
  """conv2d returns a 2d convolution layer with full stride."""
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
​
​
def max_pool_2x2(x):
  """max_pool_2x2 downsamples a feature map by 2X."""
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
​
​
def weight_variable(shape):
  """weight_variable generates a weight variable of a given shape."""
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)
​
​
def bias_variable(shape):
  """bias_variable generates a bias variable of a given shape."""
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)
​
​
# Import data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp")
# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784],name='x')
# Define loss and optimizer
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None])
# Build the graph for the deep net
y_conv, keep_prob = deepnn(x)
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    cross_entropy = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(
        labels=y_, logits=y_conv)
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
​
with tf.name_scope('adam_optimizer'):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
​
with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), y_)
    correct_prediction = tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_prediction)
​
graph_location = tempfile.mkdtemp()
print('Saving graph to: %s' % graph_location)
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(graph_location)
train_writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())
​
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(1000):
      batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
      if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
            x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
      train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
​
    print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))

    sing = np.reshape(mnist.test.images[0],(-1,784))    
    output = sess.run(y_conv,feed_dict={x:sing,keep_prob:1.0})
    print(tf.argmax(output,1).eval())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess,"/tmp/network")

Extracting /tmp/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz

Saving graph to: /tmp/tmp17hf_6c7
step 0, training accuracy 0.2
step 100, training accuracy 0.86
step 200, training accuracy 0.8
step 300, training accuracy 0.94
step 400, training accuracy 0.94
step 500, training accuracy 0.96
step 600, training accuracy 0.88
step 700, training accuracy 0.98
step 800, training accuracy 0.98
step 900, training accuracy 0.98
test accuracy 0.9663
[7]
```

If you want to restore from a new python run:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

import argparse
import sys
import tempfile
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

sess =  tf.Session() 
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/network.meta')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/tmp'))
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp")
simg = np.reshape(mnist.test.images[0],(-1,784))
op_to_restore = graph.get_tensor_by_name("fc2/MatMul:0")
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
output = sess.run(op_to_restore,feed_dict= {x:simg})
print("Result = ", np.argmax(output))
```

Comment: This didn't work. The error right now is InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Xx_1' with dtype float and shape [?,784]

Answer (score 0):

The losses are oscillating like this but the predictions don't seem to be bad. It works.

It also extracts the mnist archive repeatedly. Accuracy also can reach 0.98 with a simpler network.

```
Epoch 1 Completed Total Loss: 47.47844
Accuracy on val_set: 0.8685
Epoch 2 Completed Total Loss: 10.217445
Accuracy on val_set: 0.9
Epoch 3 Completed Total Loss: 14.013474
Accuracy on val_set: 0.9104
[2]
```

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data as input_data
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784],name='Xx')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10],name='Yy')

input = 784
n_nodes_1 = 300
n_nodes_2 = 300

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data/', one_hot=True)

def neural_network_model(data):
    variables = {'w1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input,n_nodes_1])),
               'w2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_1,n_nodes_2])),
               'w3':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_2,n_classes])),
                 'b1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_1])),
                 'b2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_2])),
                 'b3':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}
    output1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,variables['w1']),variables['b1'])
    output2 = tf.nn.relu(output1)
    output3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(output2, variables['w2']), variables['b2'])
    output4 = tf.nn.relu(output3)
    output5 = tf.add(tf.matmul(output4, variables['w3']), variables['b3'],name='last')
    return output5

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    name_of_final_layer = 'fin'
    final = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=prediction,
                                                       labels=y,name=name_of_final_layer)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(final)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
    hm_epochs = 3
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _,c=sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict={x:epoch_x,y:epoch_y})
            print("Epoch",epoch+1,"Completed Total Loss:",c)
            correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,'float'))
            print('Accuracy on val_set:',accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels}))
        #path = saver.save(sess,"net/network")
        #print("Saved to",path)
    return prediction


def eval_neural_network(prediction):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('net/network.meta')
        new_saver.restore(sess, "net/network")
        singleprediction = tf.argmax(prediction, 1)
        sing = np.reshape(mnist.test.images[1], (-1, 784))
        output = singleprediction.eval(feed_dict={x:sing},session=sess)
        digit = mnist.test.images[1].reshape((28, 28))
        plt.imshow(digit, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()
        print(output)

prediction = train_neural_network(x)

eval_neural_network(prediction)
```